# Using the useParams hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning `useParams` hook in react. I have a URL like this and need to be able to extract the letter 9 from it.

```
http://localhost:3010/9/solution
```

How can I go about this ?

Comment: React does not have useParams hook.

Comment: Have a look at this one: [useRouter hook for better routing with react-router](https://usehooks.com/useRouter/) It wraps all the hooks `useParams, useLocation, useHistory, useRouteMatch` up into a single `useRouter` hook that exposes just the data and methods we need. Hope you enjoy it!

Comment: There is an package name 'react-router-dom' that it includes useParams hook

Answer (score 42):

I'm assuming you're using react router, if you define a route like this for example:

```
<Route path="/:id/about">
 <About />
</Route>
```

Notice that you define the path with this :id notation, that means that the id will be the param in this specific case. Then you create a Link component

```
<Link to="/2/about">About</Link>
```

And in your component that in this example is the about component you can use the hook like this:

```
function About() {
 const { id } = useParams();
 return (
  <div>
   <h2>Now showing post {id}</h2>
  </div>
 );
}
```

I have this code sandbox if you want to check the result https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-nv8pn

Comment: I am using react-router-dom

Comment: Yeah this should work, it is using react-router-dom

Comment: I want to do this when the component loads. Do I need to do this in useEffect or outside the functional component?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? You can put in in the useEffect but what are you planning to do with that id?

Comment: I will use it with the useSelector to  retrieve an object from my state

Comment: I believe you can do something like const myState = useSelector(// your logic) and just do if (myState) return <TheComponent /> if not just return null, there's no need to add an useEffect unless you're doing some sort of side effects.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you are using `react-router`, then you should use Browser Router in your React app:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

and then declare a route like:

```
<Route path="/{id}/solution" component={Component} />
```

and then in your Component you'll be able to use it:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

Comment: Do I need to declare the statement above in useEffect or just within the functional component. I want to get this value when the component loads