# Exact path won't capture slug

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following along a course where I'm building a portfolio for myself in React. Everything I've done has worked thus far, except for this one issue I'm having.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about-me" component={About} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
    <Route exact path="/portfolio/:slug" component={PortfolioDetail} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

I have the switch running through my known slugs and my NoMatch is catching links that don't exist, unless I put a link that is formatted in the fashion of localhost:####/portfolio/non_existant_link.

Portfolio Detail Code:

```
import React from "react";

export default function(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Portfolio Detail for {props.match.params.slug}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

No Match code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>We couldn't find that page</h2>
            <Link to="/">Return to homepage</Link>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The instructor is using a slightly older version of react. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you show me your navigation file  probably added the wrong link inside the path

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass the slug is to use the `render()` of the route. There may be cleaner ways though so if anyone else has an answer for this I'd love to see it!

```
  <Route exact
    path="/portfolio/:slug" 
    render={(props) => (<PortfolioDetail path={props.history.location.pathname} />)} 
  />
```

Another method is the `useParams` react hook as described here: [Using the useParams hook in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998386/using-the-useparams-hook-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I figured it out so I'll type the answer that worked for me because I doubt I'm the same one running into the issue. The solution turned out to be a fix my brother (who's going through the course and has this part working) told me to try. It didn't work initially, but I think that has everything to do with a caching error. There HAS to be a space between your path and ":slug", like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavigationContainer />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about-me" component={About} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
              <Route exact path="/portfolio/ :slug" component={PortfolioDetail} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Always check your cache when you run into a bug! This is a beginner mistake, and as a beginner, I have made it, so you shouldn't have to.