# UseParams hook in React keeps returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm just making a practice recipe app that uses a GET request to show recipes which I'm mapping through into their own individual Recipe components so I can give each an edit & delete button. For some reason, I thought I setup useParams correctly as well as matched the dynamic :id with what I extracted into the useParams hook aka { id } but it keeps popping up undefined. Everything else setup with Redux has been working without errors.

Here is my App.js file:

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import Recipes from "./Recipes";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route path='/recipes/:id' component={Recipe} />
      <Route exact path='/recipes' component={Recipes} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my Recipe.js file:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteRecipe } from './actions';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


function Recipe({ recipe }) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let { id } = useParams();
    console.log('id:', id);

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        dispatch(deleteRecipe(id));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to={`/recipes/${id}`}>
           <h5>{recipe.title}</h5> 
           <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
           </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Recipe
```

Comment: Are you able the see the id in the browser url when you render the `Recipe` component ? .

Comment: Are you sure it's `id` that's undefined, and not `recipe`? It makes sense for `recipe` to be undefined; the only props passed to `<Recipe>` should be [match, location and history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are in the Recipe `show` method trying to Link to another Recipe `show`. You will need to use the `Recipes` component, with a `Link` that houses the dynamic/static `id`.  Then you can call useParams to get that id.

[Example here from previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998386/using-the-useparams-hook-in-react)