# useParams() return undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know this should be very simple. Yet, again useParamas() is returning undefined. My code is as per below:
App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import Layout from "./UI/Layout";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Pages/Home";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Patients from "./components/Pages/Patients";
import Patient from "./components/Pages/Patient";
function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Suspense>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/patients" element={<Patients />} />
          <Route path="/patients/:id" element={<Patient />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </Layout>

  );
}
```

Patient.js

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Card from "../../UI/Card";
import loading from "../../UI/loading.svg";

function Patient() {
    const { id } = useParams;
    console.log(id);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="header">
        <p>This is the page for patient with id: {id}!</p>
      </header>
      <div className="container">
        <Card>
          <div>
            <img src={loading} className="loading" alt="logo" />
          </div>
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Patient;
```

Patients.js

```
import Card from "../../UI/Card";
import loading from "../../UI/loading.svg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Patients() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="header">
        <p>This is the patients' page!</p>
      </header>
      <div className="container">
        <Card>
          <div>
            <img src={loading} className="loading" alt="logo" />
          </div>
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <Link to="/patients/12">Go to patient with id 12</Link>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Patients;
```

and index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>
);
```

Please someone let me know what is missing that id is returning undefined?
Note: I followed also from the link [Using the useParams hook in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998386/using-the-useparams-hook-in-react) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjHT_NKR_gU&t=1098s.

Comment: you forgot to call that hook, it should be ```const { id } = useParams()```; (missing parentheses)

Comment: I knew it is something very stupid.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useParams is imported and used ok, except your forgot paranthesis after useParams in Parient component:

```
function Patient() {
    const { id } = useParams()  <== here
```